How to make it work for copying files from class path (as in test run in Eclipse) and a jar file (as in production release)?
The application needs to copy some files from resource class folders to a working directory to make the application work.  It works perfect when testing in Eclipse using:
URL a = Ressources.class.getResource(RESOURCE_LOCATION);

However, it does not work when release into production with jar file, especially when the files are in subdirectories inside the jar.
How to make it work for both situations?
Tried to use class.getResourceAsStream
InputStream inputStream = Ressources.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_LOCATION);

But still not working in production.

It seems no easy one solution to meet both copying files in folder and sub folders in a class path and copying files in folder and sub folders in a jar file (since InputStream does not have the folder structures).
What I finally comes up is to first try to get access to the specified folder in a JAR file that contains the class. If failed, try to access the specified folder in the class. Below is the basic codes:

Find out where the files should be copied from:
boolean bCopyFromJar = false;
URL jarUrl=this.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
Path jarPath = null;
if (jarUrl == null) {
bCopyFromJar = false;
}else {
jarPath = Paths.get(jarUrl.toURI());
if (!Files.exists(jarPath) || !jarPath.toString().endsWith(".jar")) {
bCopyFromJar = false;
}else {
bCopyFromJar = true;
}
}

Make the copy of files
if (bCopyFromJar) { //Release runtime (Copy imported files from JAR file)
//Path to the JAR file
String jarFilePath = jarPath.toString();
 //Specify the folder path within the JAR file
 String folderPathInJar = org/myapp/myclassfolder/; //Change to yours

 //Specify the target directory to extract files
 Path workingDir = Path.of(TARGET_DIRECTORY);  //Change to yours

 // Extract all files the specific folder from the JAR to the working folder
 extractFolderFromJar(jarFilePath, folderPathInJar, workingDir, false);

}else { //as running in EClipse (Copy files from class path)
URL a = Ressources.class.getResource(IMPORTED_LOCATION);
List lstFiles = getAllFilesFromResource(a); //including recursive
for (File file : lstFiles) {
copyFileFast(file.toURI().toURL(), file.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), true);
}
a = null;
lstFiles = null;
}
private static void extractFolderFromJar(String jarFilePath, String folderPathInJar, Path targetDir, boolean bKeepOriginalStructure) throws IOException {
try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jarFilePath)) {
Enumeration entries = jarFile.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
String entryName = entry.getName();
         if (entryName.startsWith(folderPathInJar) && !entry.isDirectory()) {
             //System.out.println(" *** entryName: " + entryName);

             int n = folderPathInJar.length(); //default to keeping the original structure
             if (!bKeepOriginalStructure) {
                 //only the file name 
                 n = entryName.contains("\\")?entryName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1:(entryName.contains("/")?entryName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1:0);
             }

             //Specify the target file path
             Path targetFilePath = targetDir.resolve(entryName.substring(n)); 

             Files.createDirectories(targetFilePath.getParent());
             try (InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry)) {
                 System.out.println(" *** Copy to: " + targetFilePath.toString());
                 Files.copy(inputStream, targetFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
             }
         }
     }
 }

}
private static void copyFileFast(URL url, String out, boolean bSkipIfExists) {
File destFile = new File(TARGET_DIRECTORY+ "\" + out);
      if (bSkipIfExists) {
          if (destFile.exists()) {
              return;
          }
      }

      destFile.deleteOnExit();
      copyFileFast(url, destFile);
  }



